# Dynamically generate file-path for FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am developing a File manager app. In this app I need to provide share option also. But from API 24 and above we can't expose a file:// Uri to another app. This will throw [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html). To resolve this we should use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) with file paths.

But every app will have their own unique folder path, and we can't add every folder path to file paths like,

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="Downloads"
        path="/Download/" />
    <external-path
        name="WhatsApp"
        path="/WhatsApp/" />
</paths>
```

So is there any short way to add path for all available folders in our external memory, or is there a way to generate file path dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="Others"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

This code works for almost all folders for me. But I am not sure this will work in future also.